# Python schedule delete file

Tags: python-3.x, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to schedule a loop that every mins the code will help delete all the `.docx` files in a folder. However my code is not actually deleting any `.docx` files on the folder (I checked that the path is right and run other code like count the number of files, also add full disk access for Terminal on Mac), and the loop also receiving error.

my code:

```
import os, os.path
import time
import schedule

csv_count = len(os.listdir("/Users/xxx/Desktop/FYP 1st Draft"))

def delectfiles():
    for file in os.scandir("/Users/xxx/Desktop/FYP 1st Draft"):
        if file.name.endswith(".docx"):
            os.unlink("/Users/xxx/Desktop/FYP 1st Draft")

schedule.every().minute.do(delectfiles)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/Jedox_batch/Jedox.py", line 16, in <module>
    schedule.run_pending()

  File "/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/Jedox_batch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 780, in run_pending
    default_scheduler.run_pending()

  File "/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/Jedox_batch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 100, in run_pending
    self._run_job(job)

  File "/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/Jedox_batch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 172, in _run_job
    ret = job.run()

  File "/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/Jedox_batch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 661, in run
    ret = self.job_func()

  File "/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/Jedox_batch/Jedox.py", line 11, in delectfiles
    os.unlink("/Users/xxx/Desktop/FYP 1st Draft")

PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/xxx/Desktop/FYP 1st Draft'
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Don't you mean to do `os.unlink(file)` inside the loop? Otherwise it seems like you're just trying to unlink the directory.

Comment: @SamuelDion-Girardeau I also tried remove and it doesn't work as well, would you suggest another command i should use to delete the files? thx

Comment: No I was saying that you're not using the `file` variable inside the loop which looks like an oversight. I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/70163774 below addresses that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not appending the filename to your unlink command.
I'm not familiar with os.scandir() so I changed it to os.listdir() in my example below:

```
def delectfiles():
    for file in os.listdir("/Users/xxx/Desktop/FYP 1st Draft"):
        if file.name.endswith(".docx"):
            os.unlink(os.path.join("/Users/xxx/Desktop/FYP 1st Draft/", file))
```

Comment: thank you! it works